# Combining this piece of Javascript with another part?

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

Since I am a complete n00b in every aspect when it comes down to JS, JQuery and PHP, I will be needing some help.

Probably it's really simple for someone with basic knowledge of JS, but it ain't that simple for me.

I have the following part in my index.php:

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="http://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/track?HTMLVersion=5.0&loc=nl_NL&Requester=UPSHome&WBPM_lid=homepage%2Fct1.html_pnl_trk" target="_blank" >
<input type="text" value="" name="trackNums" id="ups" />
<input type="hidden" name="track.x" value="Traceren">
<input type="hidden" name="loc" value="nl_NL">
<input type="image" src="afbeeldingen/search_btn.png" id="searchsubmit" />
</form>
```

In the .js file I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ups").attr("value", "UPS Trackingscode...");
    var text = "UPS Trackingscode...";
    $("#ups").focus(function() {
        $(this).addClass("active");
        if($(this).attr("value") == text) $(this).attr("value", "");
    });
    $("#ups").blur(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
        if($(this).attr("value") == "") $(this).attr("value", text);
    });
});
```

I added this (at the top of) the .js file:

```
function removeSpaces(string) {
    return string.split(' ').join('');
}
```

But when I add this part to the index.php (form-section) it doesn't work:

```
<input type="text" onblur="this.value=removeSpaces(this.value);">
```

I guess I have to incorporate it to the current JS as well, but I have no clue how to do this or what to change / add.

What I am trying to achieve here, is that whenever I paste a trackingcode into the text field, it should automatically remove the spaces (if there are any, because a bad copy/paste action).

It's not for any special website, but just for my personal use, so I can track packages more easily from my own starting page.

I hope I explained it correctly. Probably it takes less than a minute for someone with basic JS skills, but for me it's very difficult. :(

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: If it's for your personal use, then just add `placeholder="UPS Trackingscode..."` to your element and throw all of that JS in the toilet.

Comment: just a sidenote: instead of split+join use a regex: `string.replace(/\s*/g,"")`

Comment: Well a much more efficient way of replacing all spaces would be `str.replace(/\s/g,'')`.  Have you tried isolating the function and testing?

Comment: Where do I add `string.replace(/\s*/g,"")`? Like mentioned above. I am a complete noob at this. I can find my way around by mixing pieces of code and examples. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function itself is working well. It's solely a scoping issue. You have two options:

1) You move your function outside the `$(document).ready(function() { })` part

2) You remove the `onblur="this.value=removeSpaces(this.value);"` from your element, discard your function and write an according event-handler

```
// identifier or class needed to target the element, i use id="target"
$("#target").on("focusout",function(){
   this.value = this.value.replace(/\s*/g,"");
});
```

The second way (using event handlers) is considered the cleaner and better way. But valid are both.

Sidenotes:

to remove spaces from your string, it's better to use the [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method with an according regular expression `/\s*/g` (replace zero or more whitespaces `\s*` in your entire string (globally `g`) ).

Instead of  `$(this).attr("value")` use [`$(this).val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: Thanks man! I had to change "target" to ups, because I am using other postal tracking services as well. But your code works perfectly. Highly appreciate your help! :D

Comment: You are wolcome;) Which choice did you take - 1 or 2 ?

Comment: I took the first one; since it's my own personal starting page and because I saw that earlier then the rest of your message (after edit). I applied it now to the other tracking sites from different package services and really works perfectly. So thank you once again for the really fast help! :)